# Can the maze be solved?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, graph-theory, path-finding, maze

### Task

- Print 0 if an `n*m` maze cannot be solved
- Print 1 if an `n*m` maze can  be solved (in 1 or more ways)

(so I'm not asking for paths but if it's possible to solve!!!)

### Example

Input array(2d):

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

XXXXXXXXX
XS     XX
X     X X
X    X  X
XX     FX
XXXXXXXXX

0 = can pass through
1 = can not pass trough
[0][n] is the last block of the first line
[m][0] is the first block of the last line
```

**Rule**
The start position is 0,0 and the end position is n,m
You can only move horizontally and vertically
Shortest code wins

Comment: Should the input be a string or an array?

Comment: whatever is shorter

Comment: If there is a 1 (wall) at (n,m) should the code return 0?

Comment: (Same for a wall at (0,0)?)

Comment: You say it's a n×m maze, but your indexing implies that it's an (n+1)×(m+1) maze.

Comment: I am looking forward to the regex solution=)

Answer (score 8):

## Dyalog APL, 27 characters

[`⊃⌽∨.∧⍨⍣≡1≥+/¨|∘.-⍨,(~×⍳∘⍴)⎕`](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2283%u233D%u2228.%u2227%u2368%u2363%u22611%u2265+/%A8%7C%u2218.-%u2368%2C%28%7E%D7%u2373%u2218%u2374%29%20%204%207%u23740%200%200%200%200%200%201%20%200%200%200%200%200%201%200%20%200%200%200%200%201%200%200%20%201%200%200%200%200%200%200&run)

`⎕` evaluated input.  APL distinguishes between a matrix and a vector of vectors.  This program assumes that the input is a matrix.

`(~×⍳∘⍴)A` is a fork equivalent to `(~A) × ⍳⍴A`.  It's needed to avoid mentioning `⎕` twice or introducing a variable.

`⍴A` is the shape of `A`.  For a 4-by-7 matrix the shape is `4 7`.

`⍳` is the index generator.  `⍳4` is `1 2 3 4`.  `⍳4 7` is the vectors `(1 1)(1 2)...(4 7)` arranged in a 4-by-7 matrix.

`~A` flips the bits of `A`.

`×` by multiplying `⍳⍴A` by the flipped bits, we preserve the coordinates of all free cells and turn all walls into `0 0`.

`,` ravels the matrix of coordinate pairs, i.e. linearizes it into a vector.  In this case the vector will consist of pairs.

`∘.-⍨A` or `A∘.-A` subtracts elements of `A` pairwise.  Note that here the elements of `A` are themselves pairs.

`|` absolute value

`+/¨` sum each pair of absolute values.  This gives us the grid distances between every pair of cells in the maze, save for walls.

`1≥` we are only intrested in neighbours at a distance no more than 1, this also excludes walls.  Now we have a graph's adjacency matrix.

`∨.∧⍨⍣≡` Floyd--Warshall's transitive closure algorithm

`(f⍣n)A` (not used here) where `n` is an integer is the power operator.  It applies `f` to `A` `n` times: `f f ... f A`.

`(f⍣g)A` where `g` is a function, is the fixed point operator, a.k.a. "power limit".  It keeps on computing the series `A`, `f A`, `f f A`, ... until `((f⍣i)A) g ((f⍣(i+1))A)` returns true for some `i`.  In this case we use match (`≡`) as `g`.

`∨.∧⍨A` or `A∨.∧A` is a step in Floyd's algorithm.  `f.g` is a generalisation of matrix multiplication (`+.×`), here we use conjunction (`∧`) and disjunction (`∨`) in place of `+` and `×`.

`⊃⌽`  After `⍣≡` has applied the step enough times and reached a stable state, we must look up the top-right corner of the matrix to get the result, so we flip it (`⌽`) and take the first, top-left item (`⊃`).

[Visualization of `⍣≡`'s steps](http://tryapl.org/?a=a%u21904%207%u23740%200%200%200%200%200%201%200%200%200%200%200%201%200%200%200%200%200%201%200%200%201%200%200%200%200%200%200%20%u22C4%20%7B%27.%23%27%5B1+%28%u2374a%29%u2374%u2228.%u2227%u2368%u2363%u2375%u22A21%u2265+/%A8%7C%u2218.-%u2368%2C%28%7E%D7%u2373%u2218%u2374%29a%5D%7D%A8%AF1+%u23736&run)

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, <strike>42</strike> <strike>41</strike> <strike>39</strike> <strike>36</strike> 35 bytes

```
Wq3>~_s,{{[{_2$+0<{e<_}*}*]}%z}*sW=
```

Based on the ideas in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40204/25180).

4 bytes thanks to Optimizer.

Input format:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 1] [0 0 0 0 0 1 0] [0 0 0 0 1 0 0] [1 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: @Optimizer Thanks for that. But then I found a shorter way...

Comment: `q2Wts~_s,{{[{_2$+0<{e<_}*}*]}%z}*sW=` - 36. Although it assumes that the first three characters of the input will be `[[0`

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 164 bytes

```py
def s(a):
 d=[(0,0)]
 while d:i,j=d.pop();a[i][j]=2;d+=[(x,y)for x,y in[(i-1,j),(i,j-1),(i+1,j),(i,j+1)]if len(a[0])>y>-1<x<len(a)and a[x][y]<1]
 return a[-1][-1]>1
```

I was reluctant to post this because it's practically how I'd normally do flood fill, just lightly golfed.  But here it is anyway.

Comment: `(x,y)` is in `[(i-1,j),(i,j-1),(i+1,j),(i,j+1)]` iff `abs(x-i)+abs(y-j)<2`, although I'm not sure if that can help

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 73 bytes

69 bytes of code + 4 bytes for `-n0E` (not sure how the tags where counted in 2014, so I counted them for 4 instead of 2, but it doesn't matter a lot).

```pl
/.*/;s/(^0|A)(.{@{+}})?0/A$2A/s||s/0(.{@{+}})?A/A$1A/s?redo:say/A$/+0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdPMMuEqLUxXSUhNLSotSFdSLEyvVrf/r62npWxfra8QZ1DhqauhVO1Rr19Zq2hvoO6oYOeoX19QU6xsghB2BwoZAYfui1JR8K6AJQL6@tsH//wZgYMgFoQy4DIHAwBDKNzAAAA)
(and if you replace the `1111011` line with `1111111`, the maze isn't solvable anymore, and the output will be `0` instead of `1` : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdPMMuEqLUxXSUhNLSotSFdSLEyvVrf/r62npWxfra8QZ1DhqauhVO1Rr19Zq2hvoO6oYOeoX19QU6xsghB2BwoZAYfui1JR8K6AJQL6@tsH//wZgYMgFoQy4DCEAwjcwAAA))

**Explanations:**

This code will find every reachable cell of the maze (and mark them with a `A`): if a cell touches a cell marked with a `A`, the it's reachable and we mark it with a `A` too; and we do that again (`redo`). That's done thanks to two regex: `s/(^0|A)(.{@{+}})?0/A$2A/s` checks if a space is on the right or the bottom of a `A`, while `s/0(.{@{+}})?A/A$1A/s` checks if a space is on the left or on top of a `A`. At the end, if the last cell contains a `A` it's reachable, otherwise it's not (that's what `say/A$/+0` checks; the `+0` is here to make sure the result will be `0` or `1` instead of *empty string* and `1`).
Note that `/.*/` will match an entire line, thus setting `@+` to the index of the end of the first line, which happens to be the size of a line, which allow use to use `.{@{+}}` to match exactly as many character as there are on a line. (`@{+}` is equivalent to `@+`, but only the former can be used in regex)

Comment: For [this test case](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdPMMuEqLUxXSUhNLSotSFdSLEyvVrf/r62npWxfra8QZ1DhqauhVO1Rr19Zq2hvoO6oYOeoX19QU6xsghB2BwoZAYfui1JR8K6AJCoa6@gYq@v//G4CBIReEMuAyNDQ0AGIuqDgA), your code considers the maze solvable even if the final position is `1`.

Comment: @Jitse Good catch. Actually, it was because the TIO links were not using the right code (I guess it was some earlier version and I didn't spot it). The answer is still valid, and I've updated the TIO links. Your example works then fine: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdPMMuEqLUxXSUhNLSotSFdSLEyvVrf/r62npWxfra8QZ1DhqauhVO1Rr19Zq2hvoO6oYOeoX19QU6xsghB2BwoZAYfui1JR8K6AJQL6@tsH//wZgYMgFoQy4DA0NDYCYCyoOAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks for the clarification, I like this approach.

Comment: @Jitse thanks, that's one of my favorite golfs :)

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>133</s> <s>130</s> 129 characters

```
a=eval gets
f=->x,y{a[x][y]=1
[[-1,0],[1,0],[0,-1],[0,1]].map{|o|d,e=x+o[0],y+o[1]
f[d,e]if a[d]&&a[d][e]==0}}
f[0,0]
p a[-1][-1]
```

Input on STDIN, outputs `1` or `0` on STDOUT.

Annoyingly long. It simply does a flood-fill of `1`s from `(0, 0)`, and then checks to see whether the "end" square is a `1`.

Comment: Will this treat the maze as solvable if it already contains a 1 at (n,m)?

Answer (score 2):

#### Java, 418 bytes

```
import java.util.Scanner;public class Solvable{static int w,h;public static void main(String[] a){String[]i=new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(";");h=i.length+2;w=i[0].length()+2;int[]m=new int[w * h];for(int x=1;x<w-1;x++)for(int y=1;y<h-1;y++)m[y*w+x]=i[y-1].charAt(x-1)<'.'?0:1;f(m,w+1);System.out.println(m[w*h-w-2]>0?0:1);}static void f(int[]m,int i){if(m[i]>0){m[i]--;f(m,i-1);f(m,i+1);f(m,i-w);f(m,i+w);}}}
```

My first code golf. I don't know why I chose Java - it's so bad for golfing xD

Example maze would be inputted via stdin like this:

```
......#;.....#.;....#..;#......
```

Comment: Pro tip: name your class something one character long, ditch the space between `String[]` and `a`, and take input from command line arguments rather than StdIn, which is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 184 <s>188</s>

```py
def f(a,x=0,y=0,h=[]):s=h+[[x,y]];X,Y=len(a[0]),len(a);return([x,y]in h)==(x>=X)==(y>=Y)==(x<0)==(y<0)==a[y][x]<(x==X-1and y==Y-1or f(a,x-1,y,s)|f(a,x+1,y,s)|f(a,x,y-1,s)|f(a,x,y+1,s))
```

This got much longer than I thought it would be :( Anyway, I'll add an explanation once I can't golf it any longer.

Answer (score 1):

### J, 75 chars

Powering of the adjacency matrix (very time and memory inefficient). *(Is it called powering in English?)*

```
   ({.@{:@(+./ .*.^:_~)@(+:/~@,*2>(>@[+/@:|@:->@])"0/~@,@(i.@#<@,"0/i.@#@|:)))
```

Some test cases:

```
   m1=. 0 0 0 0 0 0 1,. 0 0 0 0 0 1 0,.  0 0 0 0 1 0 0,. 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
   m2=. 0 1 1 ,. 0 0 0
   m3=. 0 1 0 ,. 1 1 0
   m4=. 0 1 1 0 ,. 0 0 1 0
   ({.@{:@(+./ .*.^:_~)@(+:/~@,*2>(>@[+/@:|@:->@])"0/~@,@(i.@#<@,"0/i.@#@|:))) every m1;m2;m3;m4
1 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 136 bytes

```python
def f(g,x=0,*p):w=len(g[0])+1;l=w*len(g);return~x%w*(-1<x<l)*~-(x in p)and any(g[x//w][x%w]and f(g,x+a,*p,x)for a in(1,-1,w,-w))or-~x==l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY/NCoMwEITvPkUuhawmmNBba55Ecgj4U0GiBEvixVe3qUX7k4K9NHPa4cvsbD8Ol04f57koK1ThmjjBSNzDyYq21LjOmYSEn1th42WGsymHq9GTO9gYU565rIV4otihRqMelC6Q0qP/6NLUytxj8u4t0Yny0cRB1RmkPI85oZxYQi1AZ@jkhGjn3jR6wBXOc064JBFa3zJLgCh6Rdg@8p7CQoT9sugTYXtd2NeUTUHx1Q/LrH54yVP/XvXQtmq@AQ)

Uses `0` for wall, `1` for free space.

Port of my answer to [Find the shortest route on an ASCII road](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195042/87681).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 184 bytes

```python
f=lambda m,x=0,y=0,n=0:n<len(m)*len(m[0])and m[x][y]<1and((x,y)==(len(m)-1,len(m[0])-1)or any(0<=i<len(m)and 0<=j<len(m[0])and f(m,i,j,n+1)for i,j in[(x-1,y),(x,y-1),(x+1,y),(x,y+1)]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBCsIwEEX3niLLiY6QwZ00JwlZVLRYMaOULpLT16m1NbYKUtLJhzfvQ@6pPd9413WVvZbhcCxVwGgNJjlszZ6L64kh6PVzOON1yUcVXPQu@YIkAERM2loYwC3hhG5J3xpVcgJT2Ppl6vclXooPYwUBa7wgb0hXsiR3VbODKL6kse8Qm8zNlIX0Wnf3puYWKnDO4Psjj1kmNFmm/i@ZMt54ca1mrnFnmktm6KG3b8HQzEMLhv7smjP0rSvvmbp/3ce36d/xAQ)