# Flood-fill a 2D grid

Tags: code-golf, array, grid

## Challenge description

Let's call a two-dimentional, rectangular array (meaning its every subarray has the same length), a **grid**. Every unit of a grid is either an **empty space** or a **border**. In a grid of characters, empty space is represented by a single whitespace; any other character is treated as a border. Sample grids (`+`'s, `|`'s and `-`'s added for readability - *they are not part of the grid*):

```
+----+
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
+----+  an empty 4x5 grid

+------+
|      |
|  #   |
|  #   |
+------+  a 6x3 grid with 2 borders

+----------+
|          |
|          |
|  #####   |
|  #   #   |
| ##   # <------ enclosed area
| #    #   |
| ######   |
|          |
+----------+  a 10x8 grid with an enclosed area
```

Given a 2D grid and a pair of coordinates, fill the enclosed area surrounding the point represented by the coordinates.

## Sample inputs / outputs

**1)**

```
0 0
+----------+      +----------+
|          |      |XXXXXXXXXX|
|          |  ->  |XXXXXXXXXX|
|          |      |XXXXXXXXXX|
+----------+      +----------+
```

**2)**

```
6 5
+-----------------+      +-----------------+
|                 |      |                 |
|                 |      |                 |
|    ########     |      |    ########     |
|    #       #    |      |    #XXXXXXX#    |
|    #    ####    |      |    #XXXX####    |
|    #    #       |      |    #XXXX#       |
|    #    #       |  ->  |    #XXXX#       |
|    #    #       |      |    #XXXX#       |
|     ####        |      |     ####        |
|                 |      |                 |
|                 |      |                 |
+-----------------+      +-----------------+
```

**3)**

```
4 6
+-----------------+      +-----------------+
|                 |      |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|    ####         |      |XXXX####XXXXXXXXX|
|   #    #        |  ->  |XXX#    #XXXXXXXX|
|    ####         |      |XXXX####XXXXXXXXX|
|                 |      |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
+-----------------+      +-----------------+
```

**4)**

```
4 5
+-----------------+      +-----------------+      +-----------------+ 
|                 |      |                 |      |                 |
|                 |      |                 |      |                 |
|    ####         |      |    ####         |      |     XXXX        |
|    ####         |  ->  |    ####         |  or  |     XXXX        |
|    ####         |      |    ####         |      |     XXXX        |
|                 |      |                 |      |                 |
+-----------------+      +-----------------+      +-----------------+
```

**5)**

```
2 6
+----------------+      +----------------+
|                |      |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|                |      |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|                |      |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|                |  ->  |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|                |      |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB|      |BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB|
|                |      |                |
|                |      |                |
+----------------+      +----------------+
```

## Notes

- An empty grid is considered enclosed, i.e. borders are implicitly situated along the edges of the grid as well (see examples 1. and 5.),
- A corner of an enclosed area doesn't need to be L-shaped. The following two areas are therefore equivalent:

```
####         ##
#  #        #  #
#  #   ==   #  #
#  #        #  #
####         ##
```

- If a unit under the coordinates happens to be a border you can either leave the grid unchanged (as in example 4.) or treat it as an empty space,
- You can choose any character for filler / empty space as long as you include this information in the submission,
- If using a type other than `char` suits your purposes better, you can use `ints` (`0` for empty space, `1` for border) or `booleans` (`true` and `false` respectively) or any other type - just make sure to include this information in your submission,
- Coordinates used in the examples above are 0-indexed `(row, column)` coordinates, as it's more convenient for two-dimensional array. If you want to use `(column, row)` (cartesian) system and/or non-0-indexed coordinates, specify it in your submission.
- If you don't know where to start, check out [Wikipedia article on flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)
- Remember that this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so make your code as short as possible!

Comment: Related: [1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42707/194), [2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17196/194), [3](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32015/194), [4](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6693/194), possibly more.

Comment: Might be worth having a test case with a single border unit at the position of the coordinates, to show that there are two valid outputs: Either the grid is all filled or the grid is unchanged. (If I have understood your 3rd note correctly.)

Comment: See ex. 4) update

Comment: I don't get how you get your alternative example 4. That appears to be destroying border cells other than the specified input square.

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB, <s>30</s> 7 bytes

As we can use logical inputs instead of strings, we can use the bare function, as it is:

```
@imfill
```

This is an anonymous function. For the usage, we have to assume a name, e.g. `f=@`[`imfill`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html). Then we can just evaluate it as `f(input,point)`, where `input` is a logical matrix, e.g. `[0,0;0,1]`, and `point` is a 2d-vector with 1-based coordinates, e.g. `[1,2]`.

Old version working on strings:

```
@(a,p)[imfill(a>32,p)*3+32,'']
```

This anonymous function accepts the input as well as a vector with the coordinates (1-based index). The function `imfill` does exactly what we need, but operates only on binary images. That is why we convert the input matrix to a logical array (where `#` are the boundaries, and   (spaces) are the void), performs the filling and is then converted back. (again `#` is filled, space is not filled).

Thanks @LuisMendo for -<s>1</s> byte.

Comment: For the string version, you can replace `~=32` by `>32`

Answer (score 4):

## C, 162 bytes

```c
w,l;char*d;f(z){z<0||z>l||d[z]^32||++d[z]&&f(z+1)+f(z-1)+f(z+w)+f(z-w);}main(c,v)char**v;{l=strlen(d=v[3]),w=strchr(d,10)-d+1,f(atoi(v[2])*w+atoi(v[1]));puts(d);}
```

Takes input from arguments (`./floodfill X Y grid`). Grid must contain `\n` or `\r\n` between each line, final newline is optional. Simplest way I've found to invoke from shell:

```
./floodfill 1 0 "$(printf "   \n###\n   \n")"
# or
./floodfill 1 0 "$(cat gridfile)"
```

Outputs to stdout, using `!` for the fill character. If the start position coincides with a `#`, makes no change.

#### Breakdown:

```c
                                    // GCC is happy enough without any imports
w,l;                                // Globals (line width, total length)
char*d;                             // Global grid pointer
f(z){                               // "Fill" function - z=current cell
    z<0||z>l||                      // Check if out-of-bounds...
    d[z]^32||                       // ...or not empty
        ++d[z]&&                    // Fill cell...
        f(z+1)+f(z-1)+f(z+w)+f(z-w);// ...and continue in "+" pattern
}
main(c,v)char**v;{                  // K&R style function to save 2 bytes
    l=strlen(d=v[3]),               // Store grid & length
    w=strchr(d,10)-d+1,             // Store width of grid (including newlines)
    f(atoi(v[2])*w+atoi(v[1]));     // Parse X & Y arguments and invoke fill

    puts(d);}                       // Print the result
```

Note that this relies on modifying the input argument string, which is forbidden, so this may not work on all platforms (implicit declarations also make this non-standard).

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by changing `int w, l;` to simply `w, l;` - gcc defaults it to `int` type

Comment: @Jacajack good point! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## C - <s>263</s> <s>247</s> <s>240</s> 238 bytes

*This is <s>first</s> <s>second</s> third version, I believe code can be shrinked too.*

```c
m[99][99],x,y,a,b,c,n;f(v,w){if(m[v][w]==32){m[v][w]=88;f(v,w+1);f(v+1,w);f(v,w-1);f(v-1,w);}}main(){scanf("%d %d\n",&a,&b);for(;~(c=getchar());m[x++][y]=c,n=x>n?x:n)c==10&&++y&&(x=0);f(b+2,a+1);for(a=-1;++a<y*n+n;)putchar(m[a%n][a/n]);}
```

And readable version:

```c
m[99][99], x, y, a, b, c, n;

/*
    a, b - flood fill start coordinates
    v, w - recursive function start coordinates
    x, y - iterators
    c - character read
    m - map
    n - maximum map width found

*/


//Recursive flood function
f( v, w )
{
    if ( m[v][w] == 32 ) //If field is empty (is ' '?)
    {
        m[v][w] = 88; //Put 'X' there
        f(v,w+1);f(v+1,w); //Call itself on neighbour fields
        f(v,w-1);f(v-1,w);
    }
}

main( )
{
    //Read coordinates
    scanf( "%d %d\n", &a, &b );
    
    //Read map (put character in map, track maximum width)
    for ( ; ~( c = getchar( ) ); m[x++][y] = c, n = x > n ? x : n )
        c == 10 && ++y && ( x = 0 );
    
    //Flood map
    f( b + 2, a + 1 );

    //Draw
    for ( a = -1; ++a < y * n + n; )
            putchar( m[a % n][a / n] );     
    
}
```

Compile and run:
`gcc -o flood floodgolf.c && cat 1.txt | ./flood`

Resources:

- [Input format](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17907754/)
- [Results](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17905672/)

*Note: I'm working on `int` values. Every   (32) is treated as empty space. Any other value is treated as border. Coordinates are in format `(row, column)`*

Comment: Don't forget you can save semicolons by putting statements inside the `for` (`scanf` here), and using the first parameter of main as a cheap int declaration will work in most compilers. Also you might be able to save a bit by flattening your array (should certainly help the print loop)

Comment: @Dave That's right. I've learned a bit since I wrote this code. I think storing data in 1D array would help me to save a lot too, but obviously I don't want to copy your idea. I'll see what I can do later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 158 bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#rY4xD4IwEIX3/opu9MJh2hXhJ8DApKkdmgBJjZYGMaGLf72WiJMdzRvuy8u9exc0nvBcG@ueCwPS1LfBMg2k/YDkCkg/jLRjK3ooCTXji1dr1VBt@0i@ajeiWq5KelXus@bHmChEzGyQfwF9IXbIBZCOxXIgbjZ2yS42O1wnY9ldO/ZYZtQAIUgpMCGF0ee7fv2N/@Gn76f@UUjj6hs). Simple recursive solution

```
a,X,Y=input()
M=len(a)
N=len(a[0])
def R(x,y):
 if~0<x<M and~0<y<N and a[x][y]:a[x][y]=0;R(x-1,y);R(x+1,y);R(x,y-1);R(x,y+1)
R(X,Y)
print'\n'.join(map(str,a))
```

0-indexed in row-column order

1 - empty space, 0 - filled space

Takes input as array of arrays of 1 and 0, and two numbers

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 129 + 1 (-a) = 130 bytes

```perl
sub f{my($r,$c)=@_;$a[$r][$c]eq$"&&($a[$r][$c]=X)&&map{f($r+$_,$c);f($r,$c+$_)}-1,1}@a=map[/./g],<>;f$F[0]+1,$F[1]+1;say@$_ for@a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY3BC4IwGMXv/RWSH0OZUwfZZRk7desejCFLXASZpnUQ9V9vrTwEEvQuj/fjve@ri@aSGNM@jo7uy86DJoDcT3nGQAlopIBcFjdYIuR9QXrwESpV3Wvbx5C9J0xPWxv9kdCAjlyltiOiMDrJYLNlGnYilpgG1ql11qqOQ@boquHKmJWzXmAyF14MzlzDxFyrGftk939vfu/H32dV38/VtTVkn4QxjQ1RLw)

**How?**

```perl
sub f{   # recursive subroutine
  my($r,$c)=@_; # taking row and column as inputs
  $a[$r][$c]eq$"&&  # using Boolean short circuit as an 'if' statement to 
                    # check if the current position in the global array is blank
  ($a[$r][$c]=X)&&  # then setting it to 'X'
  map{f($r+$_,$c);f($r,$c+$_)}-1,1 # and checking the four surrounding spaces
}
# -a command line option implicitly splits the first line into the @F array
@a=map[/./g],<>;    # put the input in a 2-D array
f$F[0]+1,$F[1]+1;   # start the fill at the given position, correcting for
                    # Perl's 0 based arrays
say@$_ for@a        # output the resulting pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 53 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[©g_#®ć©d®IgIнg‚‹«PisD®нèD®θèi2®θǝ®нǝs1ÝÂ‚D(«ε®+}ìë\s
```

Input-coordinate as a wrapped pair of integers \$[[x,y]]\$, and input-grid as a matrix of 1s and 0s for empty spaces and borders respectively. Flood-fills with 2s.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@tDK9HjlQ@uOtB9amXJonWe654W96Y8aZj1q2HlodUBmscuhdRf2Hl4BpM7tOLwi0whEH58LEjw@t9jw8NzDTUDFLhqHVp/bemiddu3hNYdXxxT/j/U6tPt/dLSZjmlsLFd0tKEOARirQ5IaAzSIXQ2qfgO8atBMwqEGt3uoo8YQ00dkhQ9uNbH/dXXz8nVzEqsqAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpSbKWgZF@ZoOMS6nVot05lgtL/6EMr0@OVD6070n5oZcqhdRHpERf2pj9qmPWoYeeh1QGZxS6H1l3Ye3gFkDq34/CKTCMQfXwuSPD43GLDw3MPNwEVu2gcWn1u66F12rWH1xxeHVP8X0kvTMm/tARoI9BCHZBdh7bZ/48GAkMdLDBWh0RxoES0gY5BLJChgMtQYgzCocYADWJXg6rfAK8aNJNwqMHtHuqoMcT0EVnhg1sNKGLMdEzJiRgcTkNSg9OLJJpDyAMmOmaxYAbNEhY91BDyoymtcg891BjoEIDUswsUWkbgFBH7X1c3L183J7GqEgA). (The `]J»` in the footer of the single TIO is used to pretty-print the output-matrix. Feel free to remove it to see the actual output.)

**Explanation:**

Despite being a codegolf language, 05AB1E's matrix builtins aren't too useful here. And 05AB1E's modular indexing is only a disadvantage for a challenge like this, where you want to stay within the dimension of the grid.

```python
[                  # Start an infinite loop:
 ©                 #  Store the list of coordinates in variable `®` (without
                   #  popping)
                   #  (which is the first implicit input in the first iteration)
  g_               #  If it's empty:
    #              #   Stop the infinite loop
  ©ć               #  Extract head of `®`; pop and remainder-list and first
                   #  coordinate separated to the stack
    ©              #  Store this coordinate as new variable `®` (without popping)
     d             #  Check [x>=0,y>=0]
       Ig          #  Push the amount of rows of the input-matrix
         Iнg       #  Push the amount of columns of the input-matrix
            ‚      #  Pair them together
      ®      ‹     #  Check [x<rowCount,y<columnCount]
              «    #  Merge the two lists together
               Pi  #  Pop, and if all were truthy (so [x,y] is within bounds):
 s                 #   Swap so the matrix is at the top
  D                #   Duplicate this matrix
   ®нè             #   Pop and get the x'th (of coordinate `®`) row of the matrix
      D            #   Duplicate this row
       ®θè         #   Pop and get the y'th (of coordinate `®`) cell of this row
          i        #   If this value is 1:
           2®θǝ    #    Insert a 2 at this y'th cell of the row
               ®нǝ #    Insert this modified x'th row into the matrix
 s                 #    Swap so the list of coordinates is at the top again
  1Ý               #    Push [0,1]
    Â‚             #    Bifurcate (Duplicate & Reverse copy) and pair:
                   #    [[0,1],[1,0]]
      D(«          #    Duplicate, negate, merge: [[0,1],[1,0],[0,-1],[-1,0]]
         ε®+}      #    Add coordinate `®` to each pair:
                   #    [[x,y+1],[x+1,y],[x,y-1],[x-1,y]]
             ì     #    Prepend-merge it at the front of the coordinates-list
          ë        #   Else: the value was 0 or 2 instead:
           \       #    Discard the duplicated row
            s      #    And swap so the coordinates list is at the top again
]                  # Close the open if-statements and infinite loop
 \                 # Discard the empty coordinates list
                   # (after which the matrix is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 112 bytes

```java
int f(int[][]m,int x,int y){try{if(m[x][y]==0)f(m,x+f(m,x,y+f(m,x-f(m,x,y+--m[x][y]),y)),y);}finally{return 1;}}
```

Input as a matrix of 0s and 1s for empty spaces and borders respectively. Modifies the input-matrix directly, and flood-fills with -1s.

Uses the same flood-fill recursive method I've used in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188896/52210), [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154383/52210), and [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238484/52210) of mine.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##zVZLb6wgGN33V3xhJRGNNm0X2klzl3fRR9KldUGnTstcByeIVmL87VMcmem8TG0zvRkJKHI4HA7ox5SW1Jm@/FuMU5rncEsZh/oMIJdUsvGCcQkTS5dRHMUz0larZalwLYWq2cSaRVUcqXg08rCukMpelkR1d2dVcxwDxEThNofNhHGapqoWiSwEBz9smgXAvHhO2dgIgDJjLzDTqqxHKRh/jWKguBUIIJNcWjx5ByOve2uu2iMHUkOOhPmENMQnPg5/qui7Iw/A@zvpa/w2rz8YvzPCAPww/b@L9/adOar//fjNXXNFLn911/TMsQff6@GR@Ie6ckGuTvJbOhX8UBcvT8rFU8H75Iv0X/8A52avN2freNuFu@WimQXTsU/HvWo78i5ZHlUuk5mbFdKd68goU26hv3xeyDyAaoTsykYElH5QZi/MdZyV6qHFWh2raTjEdF9ITRUAMpiJ6dLG8h/wHZ7oJsPqjNERHZ6ihaK1nky0XYCNvJBdd73cNOGv8i1kto2N0XsMU33ecQvJUvePEFTlrsy6g4WZQsRibFs7jI5/gwgKUPzEEd4QUFIBInsPtkR/aisD3YjXS76npbz2btAdCkpD2e9c612bm8UH)

**Explanation:**

```java
// Recursive method with integer matrix & x,y parameters and integer return-type
int f(int[][]m,int x,int y){
  try{if(m[x][y]==0)   //  If the current cell-value is 0:
            --m[x][y]  //   Decrement the current cell-value to -1
           f(m,x,y+...)//   Recursive call west
          f(m,x-...,y) //   Recursive call north
         f(m,x,y+...)  //   Recursive call east
        f(m,x+...,y);  //   Recursive call south
  }finally{            //  Catch and swallow any ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions
                       //  (shorter than manual if-checks)
           return 1;}  //  Always result in 1, so we use it to our advantage to
                       //  save bytes here by nesting, instead of having four
                       //  loose calls to each direction)
```