# Is there a stable way to stack these?

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem

If we have a binary matrix then we will say that a \$1\$ is stable if it is in the bottom row or it is directly adjacent to a \$1\$ which is stable.

In other words there must be a path to the bottom row consisting only of \$1\$s.

So in the following matrix the \$1\$s highlighted in red are not stable.

$$
0110\color{red}{1}0\\
0100\color{red}{11}\\
110000\\
$$

A matrix is stable if every \$1\$ in it is stable.

Your task is to take a matrix or list of rows and determine if there is someway to rearrange the rows into a stable matrix.

The example above can be if we swap the top and bottom row:

$$
110000\\
011010\\
010011\\
$$

But the following matrix cannot:

$$
01010\\
10101\\
00000
$$

You may take input in any reasonable format.  You may also assume that there is at least one row and that all rows are at least 1 element long. You should output one of two distinct values if it is possible to rearrange the rows into a stable matrix and the other if it is not.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to minimize your source code with answers being scored in bytes.

### Test cases

```
000
000
000
-> True
1
-> True
011010
010011
110000
-> True
01010
10101
00000
-> False
01010
10101
01110
-> True
01010
01100
00011
10101
-> False
10
01
-> False
```

Comment: Why the third test case is true?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena That's the case we use as an example in the body of the post.  Swap the top and bottom rows.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
Zy:Y@!"2G@Y)tQ&v4&1ZImvA
```

Input is a binary matrix. Output is `0` if stable, `1` otherwise.

Try it at [MATL online!](https://matl.io/?code=Zy%3AY%40%21%222G%40Y%29tQ%26v4%261ZImvA&inputs=%5B0+1+1+0+1+0%3B+0+1+0+0+1+1%3B+1+1+0+0+0+0%5D&version=22.4.0) Or [verify all test cases](https://matl.suever.net/?code=%60%0AZy%3AY%40%21%222G%40Y%29tQ%26v4%261ZImvA%0A%5DDZxT&inputs=%5B0+0+0%3B+0+0+0%3B+0+0+0%5D%0A%5B1%5D%0A%5B0+1+1+0+1+0%3B+0+1+0+0+1+1%3B+1+1+0+0+0+0%5D%0A%5B0+1+0+1+0%3B+1+0+1+0+1%3B+0+0+0+0+0%5D%0A%5B0+1+0+1+0%3B+1+0+1+0+1%3B+0+1+1+1+0%5D%0A%5B0+1+0+1+0%3B+0+1+1+0+0%3B+0+0+0+1+1%3B+1+0+1+0+1%5D%0A%5B1+0%3B+0+1%5D&version=22.4.0).

#### Explanation

```
Zy         % Input (implicit): binary matrixz. Size. Gives [r, c], where r and c
           % are the numbers of rows and of columns
:          % Range. Gives [1, 2, ... r] (c is ignored)
Y@         % All permutations of numbers 1, 2, ..., r. Gives an r-column matrix
           % where each row is a permutation
!"         % For each row
  2        %   Push 2
  G        %   Push input
  @Y)      %   Apply current permutation to the rows of the input
  tQ       %   Duplicate, add 1. Gives a matrix the same size as the input with
           %   all entries different from 0
  &v       %   Concatenate the two matrices vertically. This has the effect of
           %   adding a "bottom" of nonzeros to the permutation of the input
  4&1ZI    %   Connected components, using 4-neighbourhood (i.e. not diagonals)
           %   Each connected component of nonzeros is labelled 1, 2, ...
  m        %   Ismember: gives true if there is a connected component labelled
           %   with 2. This can only happen if some 1 in the input is not
           %   connected to the bottom, meaning that the current permutation
           %   is not stable
  vA       %   Concatenate vertically. All. This acts as a cumulative "and".
           %   The result is 1 if and only if all permutations so far were
           %   not stable
           % End (implicit). Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 60 bytes

```
1 e.i.@!@#(1*/@,@([:+./ .*^:_~1>:[:|@-/~$j./@#:I.@,)@,])@A.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU5NC4JAEL3vr5g08Hvc7bhhTAhB0Cm6iUmEUl466DH86zZrUWLF8pY3M4/3Xt1b6FSQaHAgBAmaESGk@92mV1DiFWlGtqv8mEJyMx1gDOgfddGplc70naK4m9cYk623SKFHYe7RGvPeE6I8X25QgYVWsMRiAbnxl0IqfsJ8irli7j2lzqFsWkhPTdk4QrQ8JAjmQglkeuQkFJjr21B@wLGToxriGMwEDy@VnKhGneQfo@/aP11M4lDG5A3yL@Gg4nX/AA)

Feels like there's a trick I'm missing, but this takes a brute force approach as follows:

- For each permutation of rows...
- Prepend of row of all ones...
- Check if the "distance of 1" graph of the 1 positions is fully connected.
- If it is, we've found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 159 bytes

```python
lambda l:any(f(0,len(l[0]),*sum(p,[]))for p in permutations(l))
f=lambda p,a,x,*t:a>len(t)or-(p:=p+t[a-1])-len(t)%a*t[0]+x<f(x*p,a,*t)>0
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/NTgMhEL7zFJMmJkBZA3oxG7dHn8DbygFTtiVhgcDUtE@/wlbrzwGY@f5mSBc8xvD4lPJyGN4Wb@b3vQHfm3ChE5XC20D9KDUTvJxmmsSoGZtihgQuQLJ5PqFBF0OhnjEyDV8JSRhxFhx7s2sRyGLuaOqHtMXRdEqz7grfGY41fnt@nuiZNxdHtpNkynEGhzZjjL6Am1PMyJfrC@VSiBtGTdomvm1SkfuCexd6Am6CtnKDN1JtKgJuO4wjn02iLqDwVZpdooxpTcD6YpsmwwD2w/j634des4qkXNXUiQN1TOSGtKGLlJJ8n24Hr/lkibpVUimpKqlkrUhtfsvkyrVLNfuVeTF1g7@Uqr5/ppa7zmypq@pmXdmf9hM)

Takes input as a 2d list. `f` is a function that checks if a matrix is stable. Then we just try every permutation, until we find a matrix that works.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 265 bytes:

```py
lambda b:any(v(i)for i in permutations(b))
from itertools import*
E=enumerate
def p(b,c,d):
 if c==len(b)-1:return 1
 try:
  for x,y in[(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0)]:
   if(y:=d+y)*b[c+x][y]:return 1
 except:return 0
v=lambda b:all(p(b,x,y)for x,l in E(b)for y,s in E(l)if s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVHLbsMgELzzFSiXQEIqyEuVJR9z7Q84PviBVSQMCHAUvt4Fu0mj9lT5YMzszOwOWhP8p1aHd2PHLr@OsurrtoJ1VqmAbkjgTlsooFDQcNsPvvJCK4dqjEFndQ@F59ZrLR0UvdHWb8Al52roua08By3voEE1aUiLMwBFB5s8l1xF/45llvvBKsgA9DZEGqZZdxLitAJRwjCJ5y79GKG4TIrYAoUsb7cBb@qi2d7LIpQvjfi94cY/ChTc8p8HSYlSljgAz4NketYlZkkwEDdDiWNMh0eXr1YrQCl9fgk7NpXZDPazhjHKooTReAMRPMWHbz7R6WCpz4M8/iVZNM/k6YVM/acEqfsknCTnOUnip4KxQnnUoaLY9JVBERCBy@f@OiHjrtCHVpy4N2ek8Gh9VWuMy7jM/5jZIvd@kfuwyH1c5D4tcp9/u8cv)

Comment: [265](https://tio.run/##pVHLbsMgELzzFSiXQEIqyEuVJR9z7Q84PviBVSQMCHAUvt4Fu0mj9lT5YMzszOwOWhP8p1aHd2PHLr@OsurrtoJ1VqmAbkjgTlsooFDQcNsPvvJCK4dqjEFndQ@F59ZrLR0UvdHWb8Al52roua08By3voEE1aUiLMwBFB5s8l1xF/45llvvBKsgA9DZEGqZZdxLitAJRwjCJ5y79GKG4TIrYAoUsb7cBb@qi2d7LIpQvjfi94cY/ChTc8p8HSYlSljgAz4NketYlZkkwEDdDiWNMh0eXr1YrQCl9fgk7NpXZDPazhjHKooTReAMRPMWHbz7R6WCpz4M8/iVZNM/k6YVM/acEqfsknCTnOUnip4KxQnnUoaLY9JVBERCBy@f@OiHjrtCHVpy4N2ek8Gh9VWuMy7jM/5jZIvd@kfuwyH1c5D4tcp9/u8cv "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: If you have a function that just returns an expression it's shorter as a lambda. When you are testing if two integers are positive and non-negative you can multiply them together instead of using and. The values in `q` don't matter, in fact we don't even need `q` for anything, and can just return directly 0 or 1. `from foo import*` is always shorter than `import foo as F`. Finally, I've split `c` to the x and y components, since they were always accessed separately.

Comment: @AnttiP Thank you, updated.

Comment: [249 bytes](https://tio.run/##pVG7bsMgFN35CpQlkJDK5KXKkrtl7Q@4HrANKhIGBCQKX@@C3aZVO1UeuHA4jwu6NoZ3ow/P1o2iehsVG9qewbZkOqIbklgYByWUGlruhmtgQRrtUYsxEM4MUAbugjHKQzlY48IGXCqurwN3LHDQcwEtaklHelwCGFxMFebIO4kptEYFoZikussbJQVusgJKAbsXxXVqtNsbh2JZ9duIN23dbe9NHZvS8XB1GlIA@b3jNpSWeQ9u1fcHlEK5d@qE544qf@OSIjOMxM9Q4dTM49FXq9UKFEXxWBl7Ol3TGexnDaUFTRJapBNI4CE@fPKZzoXmnC/y@JekyTyTpx9kzp9ekNMn4SQ5zy/J/HRhndQBCVTXm4FZlACRuHnMS0iVZoNejebEP3mrZEDrN73GuEnD@4@ZLnLvF7kPi9zHRe7TIvf5t3v8AA). Moved if statement into for loop. Replaced `except:return 0` to `except:pass`. Changed `c==len(b)-1` to `c>len(b)-2`.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 167 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,...b)=>a[0]?a.some(h=>f(a.filter(_=>_!=h),h,...b)):b[b=b.map(x=>[...x]),0].map(g=(y,x)=>(e=b[~y]||0)[x]&&++e[a=2,x]+[-1,1].map(i=>g(y+i,x)+g(y,x+i)))|!/1/.test(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7PbsIgGL/7FPOiECiFnZYlsJsvsN2QKK20smDbFVzaxOzVO4rTLTtAvu/393vXn9qXve1C1rQHM00VBxoTQgrIhZZUvWji25MBRy4qoEllXTA92HGxW/IjxMerFj4XsuAFOekODFzICA4KYqoSUnMw4iEGAsML@TWqy4VCOajVCiEjNX/Eg0IyY5hd9ZaLGozIRg@qZyuyEMLLMmc5CcYHUMCpNx9n2xuwrvwakt7ow8Y68zo2JaB4fQ7VU4I7p0sDcknZtlEor3G8rmwb3zpDXFuDCgzEd86G/bbZp/LARfiB9rdrsrkfwolSuri9TDy89WezYPeJMkZZJBmN0yIuf2U0cfPHZvuV2Wjn/1Es@v6Z5tzUOacm1d2a2N/1Gw)

Input `-1` for true and `0` for false

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 116 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,p=1)=>a.some((r,j)=>r.every((c,i)=>c?(s|=p[i],l=1):!(l=s=l>s),l=s=0)&l<=s|p&&f(b=[...a],b.splice(j,1)[0]))||++a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLTgMhFN3PV9wubO9NKQWXKnVhdGF8LHQ3kogjozS0M4Gxahy/vcKY1McCck7Og8tdmo2JVXBtN1s3j3a7rRUa1ipJamF4bFYWMbBlYoHbjQ3viBVziVbHGHvVlk4zn9wHI/QqKr@IxDIQNPZHKvbteFzjgyo550azBx5b7yqLSyapFJqo76dTs@1s7CoTbQQF94UQYndmC7gNL7aQOySkFDKJUiRUJPLbJgYtXzLHv5Uz4@M/Sabcv1DuHd7MrYNrFx3UH3rPu@BWSMNnOpwnAXNRP8g0J157012aFvGNgWNgCNQCHOzBPhxDWZrSzaT@2zK5W0@Ir1IoZHNeWNAD32Q@3RAxOL@5vuKtCdHiG@@ai@bVhpO0NyTSGg6g1HRY7JbJ6yacmuoZsUxDWD1M8VEAVM06Nt5y3zzhaFSjS4oCyyDD1PBJh9sv)

Input 0/1 matrix. Output true vs NaN.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 53 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
œʒ¬!ªÐU˜!ƶsgäΔ0δ.ø¬0*šĆ2Fø€ü3}εεÅsyøÅs«à}}X*}˜0KÙg}gĀ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6ORTkw6tUTy06vCE0NNzFI9tK04/vOTcFINzW/QO7zi0xkDr6MIjbUZuh3c8alpzeI9x7bmt57Yebi2uPLwDSB5afXhBbW2EVu3pOQbeh2em16Yfafj/PzraQMcQCEGkQawOmGcA5hkCeYZQHhDGxgIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/o5NPTTq0RvHQqsMTQk/PUTy2rTj98JJzUwzObdE7vOPQGgOtowuPtBm5Hd7xqGnN4T3Gtee2ntt6uLW48vAOIHlo9eEFtbURWrWn5xh4H56ZXpt@pOG/zv/o6GgDHSCM1UGjY3UUoqMNIZSBjiEQgkiIPIgNFgPyDKE8uB4DJKVQFlihAbHKDCG2YSqDOQPuSLgTYNohjoYpjo2NBQA).

**Explanation:**

In pseudo-code, I do the following steps (with the code-parts behind it - as you can see, the flood-fill takes up most of the bytes):

1. Get all permutations of rows of the input-matrix (`œ`)
2. Check if any permutation is truthy for the following steps (`ʒ...}gĀ`):

   1. Append a row of 1s to the matrix as new bottom (`¬!ª`)

      1. E.g. the permutation we want to check is:

         ```
          0,1,1,0,1,0
          0,1,0,0,1,1
          1,1,0,0,0,0
         ```
      2. Then it will become this with bottom row of 1s:

         ```
          0,1,1,0,1,0
          0,1,0,0,1,1
          1,1,0,0,0,0
          1,1,1,1,1,1
         ```
   2. Flood-fill the matrix, using only horizontal/vertical moves - done in a similar matter as [@Jonah's J answer for the *To find islands of 1 and 0 in matrix* challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188893/52210) (`ÐU˜!ƶsgäΔ0δ.ø¬0*šĆ2Fø€ü3}εεÅsyøÅs«à}}X*}`):

      1. We first create a matrix of the same size with unique positive integers:

         ```
           1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
           7, 8, 9,10,11,12
          13,14,15,16,17,18
          19,20,21,22,23,24
         ```
      2. Then for each cell we get the maximum among itself and its horizontal/vertical neighbors:

         ```
           7, 8, 9,10,11,12
          13,14,15,16,17,18
          19,20,21,22,23,24
          20,21,22,23,24,24
         ```
      3. Which we multiply by the matrix of 0s/1s we started with (the one from step 2.1.2):

         ```
           0, 8, 9, 0,11, 0
           0,14, 0, 0,17,18
          14,15, 0, 0, 0, 0
          20,21,22,23,24,24
         ```
      4. And we continue steps 2.2.2 and 2.2.3 until the result no longer changes:

         ```
           0,24,24, 0,18, 0
           0,24, 0, 0,18,18
          24,24, 0, 0, 0, 0
          24,24,24,24,24,24
         ```
   3. Check if there is just a single island after the flood-fill (`˜0KÙg`)

As for the actual code:

```python
œ             # Get all permutations of rows of the (implicit) input-matrix
 ʒ            # Filter this list of matrices by:
  ¬!ª         #  Append a row of 1s:
  ¬           #   Push the first row (without popping the matrix)
   !          #   Convert all 0s/1s to 1s with the faculty
    ª         #   Append this row of 1s to the matrix
  Ð           #  Triplicate the matrix
   U          #  Pop and store a copy in variable `X`
   ˜!ƶsgä     #  Pop and push a matrix of the same size with values [1,length]
   ˜          #   Flatten the matrix
    !         #   Convert everything to 1s with the faculty
     ƶ        #   Multiply every 1 by its 1-based index
      s       #   Swap so the last copy is at the top
       g      #   Pop and push its amount of rows
        ä     #   Pop and split the list into that many equal-sized parts
   Δ          #  Loop until the result no longer changes
              #  (which will be used to flood-fill the matrix):
    0δ.ø¬0*šĆ #   Surround the matrix with a border of 0s:
     δ        #    Map over each row:
    0 .ø      #     Surround it with a leading/trailing 0
        ¬     #    Push the first row (without popping)
         0*   #    Convert all 0s/1s to 0s by multiplying by 0
           š  #    Prepend this row of 0s to the matrix
            Ć #    Enclose; append its own head
    2Fø€ü3}   #   Get all 3x3 blocks of this matrix:
    2F        #    Loop 2 times:
      ø       #     Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
       €      #     Map over each row:
        ü3    #      Get all overlapping triplets of this row
          }   #    Close the loop
              #   Looking at horizontal/vertical neighbors only, get the maximum
              #   of each 3x3 block:
    εε        #    Nested map over each 3x3 block:
      Ås      #     Push its middle row
      yøÅs    #     Push its middle column
          «   #     Merge the two triplets together
           à  #     Pop and push the maximum
    }}        #    Close the nested maps
    X*        #   Then multiply each maximum by matrix `X`,
              #   so all cells that contained 0s become 0 again
   }          #  Close the flood-fill loop
    ˜         #  Flatten the matrix to a list
     0K       #  Remove all 0s
       Ù      #  Uniquify the remaining values
        g     #  Pop and push the length (only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E)
}gĀ           # After the filter: check if any permutations remain (length>=1)
              # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

[There are a bunch of 5-bytes alternatives for `˜0KÙg`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//9BwD78Mz0xV0uE7PifKODwAzgALGjxp2QgQDFUGCIApI//8fHW1koqMAwgZwFKujEG2ALAhRgiQMlQJTIGGYGCqOjQUA), but I haven't been able to find a 4-byter.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>129</s> 112 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υ⌕Ａι1≔⟦⟦⟧⟧θＦυ«≔⟦⟧ηＦθＦ⊕Ｌκ⊞η⁺⁺✂κ⁰λ¹⟦ι⟧✂κλＬκ≔ηθ»Ｆθ«≔⟦⟧ηＦＬιＦ§ικ⊞η⟦κλ⟧≔Ｅ⊟ι⟦Ｌικ⟧ιＷΦ⁻ηιΦ⁴№ιＥλ⁺π∧⁼ρ﹪ν²⊖⁻νρＦκ⊞ιλＰ↔¬⁻ηι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHBasMwDD0vXyF6ksGDZuy2U9hWKKyj0GPIIUu82kSz08TeBqPfnslp0uUyG2SjZ733JFe67CpX0jB8aUMKcGvb4A@@M/aIQsA@9BqDhI2xdUaERsIqXQnxkGR9b44W87woJJw48e46wCDgJ7mZMUY0IzcjdBIwnltbdepDWa9qfFH26DU2YpbSEvYUehzDgUylsJGwlkASUiEhNwXHK8DZBUWUmqT1xdM5maX/czWVGzG5y/zW1uo7NtosTOVRrFgI7MoW967lQgavJFwU/Zn4cBroxpBXHe6M5Y50xOI0x9y9hEcXrI9ikY@m5lsJma3x@RRK6rFj0NWBHFoJd4LLn9TfBC@8jHRiXpdGmsk8c1O0swvkTcv/6jF76x0Fr/DV@aWxcYLnYVinvJMY0mSdpnwfbj/pFw) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated strings of `0`s and `1`s and outputs a Charcoal boolean i.e. `-` if a stable stack exists, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υ⌕Ａι1
```

Input the matrix and save the positions of the `1`s in each row.

```
≔⟦⟦⟧⟧θ
```

Start building up the permutations of the rows.

```
Ｆυ«
```

Loop through the rows.

```
≔⟦⟧η
```

Start building up the permutations that include this row.

```
Ｆθ
```

Loop through the permutations of the previous rows.

```
Ｆ⊕Ｌκ
```

Loop through the possible insertion points.

```
⊞η⁺⁺✂κ⁰λ¹⟦ι⟧✂κλＬκ
```

Insert this row at that point and save it to the list of permutations.

```
≔ηθ
```

Save the list of permutations.

```
»Ｆθ«
```

Loop through all of the permutations.

```
≔⟦⟧ηＦＬιＦ§ικ⊞η⟦κλ⟧
```

List the coordinates of all the `1`s.

```
≔Ｅ⊟ι⟦Ｌικ⟧ι
```

List the coordinates of the `1`s on the bottom row, which are stable by definition.

```
ＷΦ⁻ηιΦ⁴№ιＥλ⁺π∧⁼ρ﹪ν²⊖⁻νρ
```

While there are unknown coordinates adjacent to at least one stable coordinate, ...

```
Ｆκ⊞ιλ
```

... save all the newly discovered stable coordinates.

```
Ｐ↔¬⁻ηι
```

Overwrite the output with `-` if all the coordinates were stable.